# Calculate specific measurements on bezier curve

Tags: svg, line, curve, bezier, inkscape

I'm currently using Inkscape 0.91's "Measure Path" extension to help me figure out exact measurements on a bezier curve. Right now, I have to guess, trim, remeasure, and then repeat those steps again to get a close approximation of the bezier curve length.

However, I'm wondering if there's a magical way to calculate an exact distance on a curve?

For example, if I have a wavy bezier curve that I know is 4cm long by using the Measure Path extension, then is there a way to calculate the 2cm mid-point?

Comment: The [SVG DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathElement) getTotalLength, getPointAtLength perhaps

Comment: What's wrong with the iterative approach? It converges incredibly fast, just use a binary search starting at a guess that pretends `t` is linear (e.g. if you need half length, you pick t=0.5), if you overshoot, t => t - t/2, if you undershoot, t = t + t/2, repeat? It's fast, it's cheap, it's arbitrarily accurate?